# AzCopy while source container is written

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azcopy

I tried to do some research but unable to find the answer.
Let's say you have container A.
at 1pm, container A had the following files:

1. test1.txt (inside the file is abcdefg)
2. test2.txt (inside the file is klmnopq)

AzCopy was performed to container A , copying it from storage C to storage D. It started at 1.01pm and finished at 1.05pm.

At 1.02pm, mr.X performed the following:

1. Add test3.txt inside container A
2. Modify test1.txt to "defgh"

The question is, what does end up in storage D for container A copy?

1. the original files? ie test1.txt (inside the file is abcdefg) and test2.txt (inside the file is klmnopq)
2. or something else?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The outcome depends on the specific timing of the writes/copies. AzCopy makes sure to guarantee the file integrity by checking the LastModified time of the source during the copy. In other words, whatever is at the source when AzCopy scanning happened will be locked on and copied.